# Can/should we rename [bsp] to [binary-space-partitioning] (with an alias)?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a mainsite tag of [bsp](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsp), which until today has had a tag description of simply "Binary space partitioning".

Could we rename this to [binary-space-partitioning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-space-partitioning) and keep [bsp](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsp) as an alias?

Maybe there's a good reason not to do this, like SEO, since we could've gone with this name the whole time it's been here but didn't (it *exactly* fits the old tag name length limit of 25 characters), but maybe that's just a matter of nobody asking to rename it. :P

Comment: ¯`·.¸¸·- It's done! -·.¸¸·´¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (¯`·¯`·.¸¸·´¯)
( \        / )
 ( ) Yes! ( ) 
  (/      \)  
   (.·´¯`·)
```